# Speeding up VB code used to extract data from large file and write to new file

Tags: vb.net

I am very new to VB programming and need your help. I have a 3 gb text file that has 9 columns of data that is space delimited. I need to create a new text file that only contains the first three columns that is also space delimited.

I have got a code running right now that works, however, it is taking a long time... I have estimated the time to process at 14 hours. Can one of you take a look at what I have written and suggest a more direct approach to speed this up?

```
    Dim filereader As System.IO.StreamReader
    filereader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader("K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Creek.txt")

    Dim stringReader As String
    Dim newline As String
    While filereader.ReadLine() IsNot Nothing
        If newline <> "" Then
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Shortened Creek.txt", vbCrLf, True)
        End If
        stringReader = filereader.ReadLine()
        Dim variables() = stringReader.Split(" ")
        newline = variables(0) & " " & variables(1) & " " & variables(2)
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Shortened Creek.txt", newline, True)
    End While
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Could you reduce the number of times you try to write to the file? For example, pull 1000 lines into memory, modify them, and then write those 1000 lines all at once? Instead of accessing the file for each individual line?

Comment: whats the purpose of the `If newline <> ""` line?  Doesn't that write a second copy to the file?  Rather than using `WriteAllText` to **create** and open a new `StreamWriter` for **each** line, open one (1) yourself and write to the same one over and over.  I'd also try `String.Format` in place of the `newline` string concat var

Comment: Thanks ChicagoMike and Putonix, used both of your input in my solution. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

- As Plutonix said in the comments, only write the result once (to minimize hard disk interaction).
- Use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1h0a5sy(v=vs.110).aspx) to append large strings together. I gave it a big default capacity as well, to avoid the StringBuilder allocating additional memory when it exceeds this (which makes it slower).
- You can use [StringReader.Peek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.stringreader.peek(v=vs.100).aspx) to check if there's still text left to be read from your input file.

Here is an example implementation:

```
    Const InputFile As String = "K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Creek.txt"
    Const OutPutFile As String = "K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Shortened Creek.txt"

    Dim currentLine As String

    Dim sbResult As New StringBuilder(5000000)

    Using sr As StreamReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(InputFile)
        While sr.Peek > -1
            currentLine = sr.ReadLine()

            Dim variables() = currentLine.Split(" "c)

            sbResult.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", variables(0), variables(1), variables(2)))
        End While
    End Using

    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(OutPutFile, sbResult.ToString, True)
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me get on my way to a good solution. Thanks for introducing me to stringbuilder, helped immensly!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super simple implementation.  You can compare it for speed against any other "optimization" suggestions you get...

```
    Dim inFile As String = "K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Creek.txt"
    Dim outFile As String = "K:\Documents\GRA Projects\Obed Creek\Shortened Creek.txt"

    Using inStream As New System.IO.StreamReader(inFile)
        Using outStream As New System.IO.StreamWriter(outFile, False)
            Dim values() As String
            While Not inStream.EndOfStream
                values = inStream.ReadLine().Split()
                If values.Length >= 3 Then
                    outStream.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", values(0), values(1), values(2)))
                End If
            End While
        End Using
    End Using

    MessageBox.Show("Done!")
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, took a mere 2-3 minutes where my last solution took 15. Thanks!

Comment: You might also try using local copies of the file if you have a lot of files to process.

Comment: Nice and simple. If this were my question then I would have marked it as answered. I wouldn't want some dude jumping in to passively imply that the question needs to be marked as answered. :)